# Android activity 2 related (as provided in developers section for Android training)

Tags: java, android

I am new to Android Programming and I tried executing activity 2 as provided on 
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html
 The expected output is that whatever you type in the text-box should be displayed after the click of the send button.
However, the only output that is visible is HelloWorld. Can you please let me know what changes are required to get the expected output.

I have followed exact steps provided in the tutorial.

Additional Details:
Windows OS - 8
Java 7

Thanks in advance!!

```
package com.example.myfirstapp;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class DisplayMessageActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Get the message from the intent
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
     // Create the text view
        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setTextSize(40);
        textView.setText(message);
     // Set the text view as the activity layout
        setContentView(textView);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
        }
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_display_message,
                    container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.myfirstapp.DisplayMessageActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The mistake is here:

```
setContentView(textView);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);
```

==> you call setContentView **twice** and the last one called is the one that will be used. According to the [tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html#DisplayMessage) you should just have:

```
// Set the text view as the activity layout
setContentView(textView);
```

Comment: Thanks for the revert.
I tried by commenting the        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);
However, I am asked to Force Close the application after the click of the button.

Comment: It is time to take a look at the logcat output ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you missed some steps for handling click events. Dont forget to add `onClick` inside Button element.

Also add this method in MainActivity:

```
/** Called when the user clicks the Send button */
public void sendMessage(View view) {
    // Do something in response to button
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
    String message = editText.getText().toString();
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the revert. I had already added the required code in the sendMessage method. This behavior is with the mentioned code included.